# Is it not possible to affect a :after element by hovering on another element?

Tags: html, css

Doesn't seem like it?

Basically, I have:

```css
.arrow:after {
    border-color: rgba(241, 241, 241, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #FFF;
    border-width: 8px;
    margin-left: -8px;
}

a.test:hover > .arrow:after {
    border-bottom-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="test">Link</a>
```

When I hover over "Link", `.arrow:after` should change but it doesn't. Any solutions?

Comment: You do not have anything in your html with a class of 'arrow' - is something missing?

Comment: You should always use content:"" with :after/:before pseudoelements.

Comment: The `.arrow` element is probably not a direct child of `.test`. If it is a sibling, you should use the combinator `~`. That would be: `a.test:hover ~ .arrow::after`. Also, pseudo elements need to have `content` defined, even an empty one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, if the element to be affected is

- a child
- a future sibling
- a child of a future sibling

of the element hovered.

Example (a future sibling):

```css
.arrow:after {
    border-color: rgba(241, 241, 241, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #FFF;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 8px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    content: '';
}

.test:hover ~ .arrow:after {
    border-bottom-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="test">Test</span>
<hr />
<a href="#" class="arrow">Arrow</a>
```

If you want complete freedom over their positions in `DOM`, you're looking at `javascript`.